# MySql - Stored function syntax error

Tags: mysql

SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION delete_user (uId INT) RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
    IF uID >= 0 THEN
        START TRANSACTION;
        DELETE FROM Folder WHERE u_id = uId;
        DELETE FROM `User` WHERE id = uId;
        RETURN 1;
    END IF;
    RETURN 0;
END;
```

Error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Where is the syntax error?

Comment: `START|BEGIN TRANSACTION` with no `COMMIT`?

Comment: if `auto_commit` is on then you don't need to do `start transaction;`

Comment: I'can't use START_TRANSACTION in a function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a delimiter around your function

```
delimiter |
CREATE FUNCTION delete_usr (uId INT) RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
    IF uID >= 0 THEN        
        DELETE FROM Folder WHERE u_id = uId;
        DELETE FROM `User` WHERE id = uId;
        RETURN 1;
    END IF;
    RETURN 0;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

The default delimiter is `;`. But if you want to create the procedure/function the DB engine would think your statement ends at the first `;`. That would lead to an incomplete statement. You can define another delimiter and then use it to mark the end of statements.

Comment: I removed "START_TRANSACTON" and added the delimiter. But still get the same error?

Comment: @Gabriel: I get no error when I try it. I added the complete function in my answer.